# Detecting Anomalies among many sets of time series

Tags: python, machine-learning, anomaly-detection

Given a large set of many two-dimensional time series curves, is there a quantitative measure of **how well some new time series fits in?** I cant find the **metric** to do this. The curves are given a sets of x-y coordinates.

`x1 = ([1,2,3],[1,2,3])
 x2 = ([2,3,5],[3,4,6])
 x3 = ([1,4,6],[3,5,5])`

**I've tried...** calculating a **"distance-from-all-other-curves" metric**, however some curves have little overlap on one or both axes as well as varying numbers of data points.

### What's a good way to approach this problem?

**Note**:

- the data could contain anomalies already.
- I'm working in python - both theoretical and practical suggestion are welcome.

Comment: Can you describe more precisely what you mean by "fits in"? Or really, what might be an underlying similarity of your time series? I think clarity on this point is crucial. If the set of time series you have are all drawn from the same underlying process with same parent distribution, then it is a matter of a statistical test. If the time series are statistically independent but have, say, the same power spectrum, similarity testing is more about testing frequency distribution.

Comment: I'm having a hard time defining a _metric_ defining what "_fits in_". **The data is a bunch of distillation curves** i.e how much of this chemical compound evaporates as we increase temperature (weight transfer percentage **x** vs temperature **y**).